# NodeJS - inconsistant client IP address detection

Tags: node.js, express, ip-address

I am having issues with consistently and correctly detecting a client's IP address after upgrading to Node 0.12.7. I am using Express, and trying the following strings to get the client's IP address:

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
req.connection.remoteAddress
req.socket.remoteAddress
req.ip
req.ips
```

All these variables return different IP addresses for some clients depending on which server the code is running on. Why would the client IP address change depending on where the code is hosted? Shouldn't the IP address be detected the same way regardless of where the code is hosted?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to give some examples of where, in terms of network topology, the servers were relative to the client? (e.g., on the same router subnet, one on the Internet and the other behind a router, server hosted on a PaaS, etc.)

Comment: @apsillers The servers are hosted in a cloud-based platform similar to Amazon web services. I'm not at liberty to say which cloud platform, however, since it is hosted in the cloud, the servers could be quite far from each other, or quite close, as in the same rack of servers. We have no way to know where the servers are physically located.

Comment: That's very helpful to know (and seems like information that is critical to answering the question and should be edited into the question). Are the clients also run in the same cloud environment, or on local physical machines, or something else?

Comment: The clients are essentially users browsing to the site with their browser, and the clients are spread out across several different states in the US. So they are not in the same cloud environment. I am unable to reproduce the issue, but clients are having issues with the correct IP address being detected.